# Generate RSS Podcast Feed from a webpage

Tags: rss, podcast

I am looking for a web service to generate a RSS feed from the contents of a webpage that is updated at regular intervals. Specifically, I need the feed to follow the specifications for a Podcast feed, for pages that contain audio material.

I found [Feed43.com](https://feed43.com) to generate a RSS feed from a webpage, but the xml file does not follow the specifications for a podcast and it is not recognized by the podcast clients.